# Accessing JsonString using Gson

Tags: java, android, gson

I am getting a response like this

```
String result = responseEntity.getBody();

{
    "FailureReason": "",
    "State": "True",
    "UserId": 1038,
    "Specified": false,
    "Name": "Java"
}
```

How would i access these JsonString. I am using `Gson` to form the `JsonString`. `I am JS Guy, when i try to access result.Name [It throws me error]`

Comment: post your logcat please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way is to use POJO. Make one `POJO` that represent the response. 
Use,

```
gson.fromJson(responseStr, responsePojoType);
```

This will return object of your POJO type. Then use POJO object's `getter` method to fetch whatever value required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android's [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) like this:

```
JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
String name = jsonResult.getString("Name");
int id = jsonResult.getInt("UserId");
```

check http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/